# How to use RegCopyTree

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I've been playing around with the C++ registry functions, and I'm trying to get RegCopyTree working, but every time I try, I get an error like

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

or

```
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.
```

I am running the program as administrator, and all other registry functions work fine.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
HKEY destinationKey;
RegCreateKeyEx(getRootKeyFromCode(rootKeyCode),
        destinationKeyPathNative, 0, NULL, 0, 0, NULL,
        &destinationKey, NULL);
RegCopyTree(INSERT_ROOT_KEY_HERE,
        INSERT_ORIGINAL_KEY_PATH_HERE, destinationKey);
RegCloseKey(destinationKey);
```

I've removed the error handling and some other irrelevant parts.

Comment: Please show the code that's failing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Destination key handle should have write access, to be able to copy to it. Calling `RegCreateKeyEx()` without specifying access mode either fails or doesn't grant write access. Try with `KEY_WRITE` or `KEY_CREATE_SUB_KEY` as sixth argument.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, the implementation of RegCopyKey() is ultimately broken.

The following code snippet:

```
HKEY source = nullptr;
LONG l1 = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, L"CLSID\\{44EC053A-400F-11D0-9DCD-00A0C90391D3}", 0, KEY_READ /* KEY_ALL_ACCESS */, &source);

HKEY destination = nullptr;
LONG l2 = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Substitute", 0, nullptr, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, nullptr, &destination, nullptr);

LONG l3 = RegCopyTree(source, nullptr, destination);
```

yields l1 = 0 (NO_ERROR), l2 = 0 (NO_ERROR), l3 = 5 (ACCESS_DENIED).

The source key (COM entry for atl.dll) exists and the destination key does not exist before calling this code. The error occurs even if I start the process with elevated privileges and open the source key with KEY_ALL_ACCESS.

By examining the registry, I found out that RegCopyTree sets the attributes of the **destination** key to KEY_READ. Subsequently, it is unable to create any more subkeys. So basically, RegCopyTree is tumbling over its own feet.

Microsoft was unable to tackle this problem, too; see the last answer in [The RegCopyTree Function](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f8756c4c-cb10-4436-815a-6d1133ad41ca/the-regcopytree-function?forum=vcgeneral)

Using RegQueryValueEx and RegSetValueEx, I can manually copy the contents from source to destination, so permissions and visibility shouldn't be the problem.
The code snippet is trivial enough. Is there still something I am overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

You should use administrator authority to run your application or you call registry functions will be failed.

Comment: It depends on permissions of what you're trying to read/write. So no, you don't necessary have to be a local admin.